# how to use a previously generated onion domain?

Tags: onion-routing, customization

this is probably a really dumb question but, I can't find any info about it. For what I see this exact topic has not been addressed before.

I am running a onion service with a hostname generated by tor. I don't want to use it though, I want to use one of my old onion domains.

From what I know, the domain is generated based on the private key.

Can I paste the the old hostname and old private key inside the HiddenService folder and replace the one generated by tor?

Will that work?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just copy over the contents of the old hidden service directory to the new one. Make sure your torrc file specifies the same hidden service version (for example if your old service was a v3 service, make sure you use `HiddenServiceVersion 3`), and make sure to reload your tor configuration (or just restart tor).

Related links:

https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2012-August/025068.html
https://askubuntu.com/questions/90294/can-i-migrate-a-tor-hiddenservice-from-one-user-pc-to-another

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will definitely try that